# openCV: Issue with cv2.VideoCapture(0) and cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

After `cap.release()` the only Frame is getting closed, webcam light is still **ON**.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1) if i give '-1' instead of '0' then light is getting OFF 
#but camera is not working because i don't have second camera to laptop.


while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cap.isOpened() #returns False
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

By pressing '*q*', the Frame is getting closed but webcam light is still ON.

How to **OFF** the webcam? (It is getting OFF after python shell is closed.)

If possible, tell me the path of `cv2.VideoCapture()` class source code.

Answer (score 0):

Set `OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF=0` in your environment variables. Seems like there is an instance leak in `opencv` library.  If you're on windows maybe use `setx` in your `cmd` to set the value `setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0`.

Reference to the issue : [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12301)

And it looks like the issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/12393) too. So try updating your opencv library or reinstalling altogether. 
That should solve your problem.

Comment: Present i am using `opencv-python==3.4.2.17` version. Which is latest, I think. 
`setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0`  from cmd doesn't work.

Comment: The issue was fixed on September of 2018, I guess it is not yet reflected in 3.4.2, Could you try cloning the `opencv` repo from github?

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will try.